# Confusion in step of proof for Triangle Inequality for complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, proof-verification

In one part of the proof, we say that $-\operatorname{Re}\langle z,w \rangle\leq|\langle z,w \rangle|$. Well, it is obviously true that $\operatorname{Re}\langle z,w \rangle\leq|\langle z,w \rangle|$. But what makes it true that $-\operatorname{Re}\langle z,w \rangle \le|\langle z,w \rangle|$?

Was this an error on the part of my professor? Thanks.

Comment: What is $\langle z,w\rangle$? Are you talking about complex vector spaces? Please ask a complete question - notice how, by trying to put the question in the title, you've sacrificed clarity and completeness for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $|a|\leq\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, which means that $\pm a\leq\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, regardless of sign of $a$. Since $|\langle z,w\rangle|=\sqrt{(\mathrm{Re}\langle z,w\rangle)^2+(\mathrm{Im}\langle z,w\rangle)^2}$, the inequality $\pm\mathrm{Re}\langle z,w\rangle\leq|\langle z,w\rangle|$ always holds.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say $\langle  z,w\rangle=a+ib$. Then hopefully you agree that $a\leq \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, which is what your first statement says.

Then if we replace $a$ with $-a$, hopefully you agree that the relation becomes $-a\leq \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, and so your second statement immediately follows.